# add job number to the build number in the project

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am using shell script and need to add the jenkins job number which is running currently to the BUILD NUMBER of the ios project

I am using plistbuddy to fetch the build number. I have got both the build number and job number with me but i am unable to add them. It is showing me error again n again

Script is something like this:

echo "BUILD_NUMBER is = "$BUILD_NUMBER

OUTPUT = $(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" Abc-Info.plist)

OUTPUT1 = $((OUTPUT + BUILD_NUMBER))

echo "$OUTPUT1"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynPGz.png)

Please help me what am i doing wrong

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just a tip.. You should use `xcrun agvtool what-version -terse` to grab de CFBundleVersion